# Controller isn't syncing to ps4

Tags: ps4, controllers

I used my ps4 controller on my pc via bluetooth, I now disabled bluetooth on my pc and I am trying to hook the controller up to my ps4 now, I searched it up on google and it said to plug in the controller and press the ps button but that did not work, whenever i turn the controller on it just flashes light blue and eventually turns off what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a hard reset

The process to hard-reset PS4 controller is way too easy. All

1. You need is first **turn off your console**. The Reset button is located in a tiny hole at the back of the controller near the L2 button.
2. Using a paperclip, press and hold the **Reset button** for a few seconds. This should be enough to reset your controller.
3. The next step is to once again **pair your controller** with your device.
   [image]

Simply connect the controller using the USB cable provided and then turn on your PS4 and proceed with the pairing procedure. If the connection fails, it’s because the controller is not detected by the console. This might be due to the respective USB cable. The PS4 controllers are somewhat peculiar here. It’s best to use an original Sony Micro USB cable. If you do not have one, you should try different Micro USB cables.

Now, press the PlayStation button on the controller to log into the PS4. The light bar should turn blue indicating the DualShock 4 has paired with the console.